# How to clear cache and Reload Image in Picasso?

Tags: android, picasso

I am using `Picasso` to load image in my application but i facing a issue that my image `URL` is same but image is changing from `backend` calling the same URL but `Picasso` loading the same image saved in its cache. Now i want to clear the cache for that Image and reload the image again.

What i have tried i searched on **SO** find that we can use `picasso.invalidate(fileName);` or `memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)`  but i am getting the error message in code

> Can't reslove method invalidate
>
> Can't reslove method memoryPolicy

dependency for picasso in gradle :

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
```

Comment: what about `2.5.2`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya thanks by updating version error is gone

Comment: Move ahead .Happy coding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`invalidate()` and `memoryPolicy()` were introduced in later versions of the library. To use either of them update picasso to the latest version

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Answer (score 17):

Try to use this.

```
 Picasso.with(context).invalidate(url); 
 Picasso.with(context).load(url).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE);
```

`compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'`

Answer (score 3):

append at the end of url  "?=" + System.currentTimeMillis();

Comment: Nice trick but it will always try to reload the image so not very optimal sometimes

Answer (score 0):

use okhttp client for picasso like below

```
okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
picasso = new Picasso.Builder(this)
            .downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(okHttpClient))
            .build();
```

and if it didn't work set okhttp client cache control to network

```
setCacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Picasso supports both download and error placeholders as optional
>   features and latest version in gradle.
>   Check url in your code when calling each time

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load(url)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
    .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
    .into(imageView);
```