# Picasso always showing old image not the new one from one particular URL

Tags: android, picasso

Using Picasso to load image from one particular URL, but always showing old image, not the new one

```
Picasso.get()
  .load("https://blabla.com/image/rose.png")
  .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE, NetworkPolicy.NO_STORE)
  .into(image_view)
```

dependency

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you are saying. Is the image from url changing every time?

Comment: @Harsh0021 yes exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heyy,

So you have to just put these lines

```
Picasso.with(context).load(imageUrl)
            .error(R.drawable.error)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
            .into(imageView);
```

Edit

Add .stableKey(url) in picasso

And then when loading the image again call this method

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).invalidate(url);
```

And that's done

Comment: I have not realized that I missed .memoryPolicy

Comment: tried even not getting updated image when closing and opening app, which was getting earlier

Comment: could you share the image url

Comment: sorry I cant, but I can see updated image on server

Comment: In that case try using glide, might solve your problem

Comment: tried glide too same issue, Iet me try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40459060/2289078

Comment: good new man I dont know how but now I can see the latest image without any modifications in our existing code... but I would suggest to use invalidate as well

Comment: just see my edit it help you more and dont forget to tick and upvote

Comment: I already accepted your answer and tapped as useful too

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `.memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)`